# socket communication between two device under sub-Lan

Tags: sockets

For two device both has public IP address, we can use socket IP and port to setup socket communication.

If both device do not has public IP but connect to sub-Lan then access public network through router (no port mapping in router), how can this two device setup socket connection?

[image]

For example in above diagram, how can machine A communicate with machine C?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have not set up a VPN tunnel between the two routers that connects both branches of the `192.168.1.0/24` network then the answer is: you can't.

If you set up a VPN tunnel then each side of the `192.168.1.0/24` network will be able to see the other side. Please note that the routers will need to be able to do ARP spoofing, i.e. the router for A & B will need to be able to spoof the MAC for C, i.e. intercept IP packages for C on their LAN and forward them through to the VPN to the other network half where they are delivered to C.

If you set up at least one port forwarding on one router, then you'll have other options, e.g. an SSH tunnel on C that connects to the port forward on either A & B. You can then use the -L option on C to setup port forwarding through the SSH tunnel to the other half of the network.